# Does JFoenix have an equivalent for JavaFX Spinner

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I am just wondering if JFoenix has an equivalent to JavaFX Spinner since their spinner is different? If not would you know any css to convert it to any modern version?

Comment: Why not just use the JavaFX spinner if that's what you want anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know JFoenix's spinner is used for loading while the default JavaFX spinner found in modena.css, is an integer spinner which is similar to a textfield but used specifically for integers. They are totally different from each other. Correct me if I am wrong but I believe JFoenix does not have the type of spinner you are looking for. In order to make the spinner look at par with JFoenix design you may try too manipulate the css of the default JavaFX spinner. Below I created a sample for you but you can tweak it at will to make it fit to your design. Good luck!

```
.spinner {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: black;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-background-color: none;

    -fx-padding: 0 0 3 0;   
}
.spinner .increment-arrow-button,
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.spinner .increment-arrow-button .increment-arrow,
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #007cff;
    -fx-font-size: 30px;
}

.spinner .text-field {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #bdbdbd;
}
```